# Does MySQL store the same string redundantly multiple times on disk?

Tags: mysql

If I have a large string such as `"John"` that is store many times in the same table:

```
 | Id | Name
 |----|------------
 | 1  | John
 | 2  | John
 | 3  | John
 | 4  | Bob
 | 5  | John
```

Does MySQL ever see that `"John"` is stored many times in a table with millions of rows, or will `"John"` exist on disk millions of times redundantly?

Comment: I think the answers are NO and YES

Comment: @RaymondNijland, Are you supposing that storing an integer id referencing a lookup table is a directive of normalization? It's not.

Comment: I'm mostly interested if MySQL has any internal mechanisms that would de-duplicate data in this way.

Comment: Also, would the answer change if the column is indexed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, MySQL stores strings redundantly.

In table rows, MySQL stores the string once for each row of data.

But in indexes, MySQL stores the value once, with a list of primary key references to rows where the value is found. So in indexes, it does reduce the values and store them uniquely.

Suppose MySQL were to try to detect repeated values, and store them once.

It would still have to store some identifier on each row, to indicate which of the previously-used values is associated with that row.

The number of possible unique strings is still a very large number, so the identifier itself would have to be pretty large to be able to enumerate them.

Suppose you have a VARCHAR(255). [How many possible strings can there be?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/898246/how-many-unique-character-string-can-be-made-from-62-characters) *n<sup>255</sup>* where *n* is the number of unique characters. So you'd need an identifier for your strings long enough to represent that number of possible values too.

So trying to do this wouldn't save much space after all, in the average case.